# gcd proof critique

Tags: proof-writing, fibonacci-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Question: The Fibonacci sequence is a sequence of natural numbers $A_1,A_2,A_3,...$ deﬁned as follows: $A_0 = 0, A_1 = 1$, and for all $n ≥ 2, A_n = A_{n−1} + A_{n−2}$ The 1st few numbers  of the sequence are $0, 1, 1$.

> Prove that for all $n$ in naturals, $\gcd(A_n,A_{n+1}) = 1$. Try using using these claims.

$∀n ∈N, \gcd(0,n) = n$ , $∀p,q,n,a,b ∈Z, n | a∧n | b ⇒ n | ap + bq$

*You must use contrapositive somewhere within the proof.*

> Induction Attempt:

$P(n)\iff \gcd(A_n,A_{n+1}) = 1.$

Base Case.
$P(0)$ will be shown true. Because $0$ is a natural, let $n = 0$ and 
$(A_2, A_1) = 1$ because of previously proven claims.

Induction

$∀k∈N \gcd(A_k, A_{k+1}) = 1$
we need to prove

$p(n) ⇒p(n+ 1)$
that is,
$∀k∈N \gcd(a_{k+1}, a_{k+2} = 1$

inductive step.

Take the contrapositive(required) 
$-P(n+ 1) ⇒-P(n)$
then,
$(∃n∈N, n >1∧cd(A_{n+ 1}, A_{n+ 2})) ⇒(∃n∈N, n >1∧cd(A_n, A_{n+ 1}))$

Now do I just find and plug in #s for the existential quantifier that work? Or how do you complete it(its about done right?) Why would it be $cd$ as opposed to $\gcd$ above and is the $n>1$ necessary ?

Comment: Hint:  $\,\gcd(a,a+b) = \gcd(a,b).\ $ The remark that "You must use contrapositive ..." is bizarre. Is this supposed to be an exercise on doing  contrapositive proofs, or is that remark intended merely as a hint?

Comment: I know how to do it with that hint but am restricted to the only 2 claims given... (I already used 1 with the base case (am allowed to use it again however)) and yes,it is a contrapositive exercise, with an induction framework(i guess you could say)

Comment: My edit was to fix a trivial typo.

Comment: My second edit was to change $P(n)=\gcd (A_n,A_{n+1}$ to $P(n)\iff \gcd (A_n,A_{n+1})=1.$

Answer (score 1):

If
$d | A_{n+1}$ 
and
$d | A_{n}$
then
$d | ( A_{n+1}-A_{n})
\implies d | A_{n-1}
$.

Work your way down to
$d | A_1 = 1
$.

If you want to use induction,
your theorem is:

If
$d | A_{n+1}$ 
and
$d | A_{n}$
then
for $ k \ge 1$
$d | A_{n-k}$.

We showed it for
$k=1$
and the same method
allows us to go from $k$
to $k+1$.

Note that this is not
standard induction
but what I call
moderately strong induction
in that the truth for
$k-1$ and $k$
is required to go from
$k$ to $k+1$.

Then set $k = n$
and we have
$d | A_0$
so $d = 1$.

Comment: thank but i am confused on "work you way down"... is my contrapositive (and everything i wrote before)correct ? can you explain some more if possible?

Comment: Also can you clarify where you used  ∀p,q,n,a,b∈Z,n|a∧n|b⇒n|ap+bq... I think i might see it but want to be sure.,